# Flutter - Show hide widgets in Stack without reloading the whole Scaffold with setState (Stack with GoogleMap like Uber)

Tags: flutter

I have a Stack where a GoogleMap is the first item.

I have some Containers afterwards, similar to Uber. I would like to show hide widgets, but without reloading the whole scaffold. Any tips on best to achieve it?
I am having some success with StreamBuilder, but failing with using streams as broadcast for some reason.

Comment: Can you share you code or error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StatefulBuilder to avoid reload the whole scaffold, here it's [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html).

Simple sample, you can wrap the widget you want to update with it like below;

```
StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Container(...
```